# Upload attachment to Confluence using Nifi ExecuteScript in Python

Tags: python, apache-nifi, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to upload a PDF file to Confluence using Nifi's ExecuteScript processor. I can upload the file successfully, but when I download and open it, it's BLANK. There must be something wrong with my conversion. Can anyone please help check?

So this is how I do it:

1. download the PDF file from an internal API
   [image: Nifi attributes after I download the file]
2. ExecuteScript Groovy - to convert the flowfile content to attribute

```py
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)return
def text = ''
session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
  text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
} as InputStreamCallback)

flowFile = session?.putAttribute(flowFile, "file_content", text)
session.transfer(flowFile, /*ExecuteScript.*/ REL_SUCCESS)
```

[image: attribute file_content]
3. ExecuteScript Python - to upload PDF file to Confluence

Here's my code for #3. I think something's wrong here -->

```
import json
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback

class OutputWrite(OutputStreamCallback):
  def __init__(self, obj):
  self.obj = obj
  def process(self, outputStream):
     outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(self.obj).encode('utf-8')))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
  url = 'https://myconfluence.com/rest/api/content/12345/child/attachment'
  auth = 'myauthorization'
  file_name = 'mypdf.pdf'
  file_content = flowFile.getAttribute('file_content')

  s = requests.Session()

  m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': (file_name, file_content, 'application/pdf')})
  headers = {"X-Atlassian-Token":"nocheck", "Authorization":auth, "Content-Type":m.content_type}

  r = s.post(url, data=m, headers=headers, verify=False)

  session.write(flowFile, OutputWrite(json.loads(r.text)))
  session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
  session.commit()
```

---

**UPDATE 06/28/2019**

I decided to follow Peter's advice and merge codes 1 and 2. It's still not working. Before, the PDF file is 2MB, but it's BLANK. Now, its size is 0KB. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```py
import json
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import InputStreamCallback

class PyInputStreamCallback(InputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def process(self, inputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

class OutputWrite(OutputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def process(self, outputStream):
        outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(self.obj).encode('utf-8')))

text = ''
flowFile = session.get()
if(flowFile != None):
    session.read(flowFile, PyInputStreamCallback())
    confluence_attachment_api = flowFile.getAttribute('confluence_attachment_api')
    confluence_authorization = flowFile.getAttribute('confluence_authorization')
    file_name = flowFile.getAttribute('file_name')

    s = requests.Session()
    m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': (file_name, text, 'application/pdf')})
    headers = {"X-Atlassian-Token":"nocheck", "Authorization":confluence_authorization, "Content-Type":m.content_type}
    r = s.post(confluence_attachment_api, data=m, headers=headers, verify=False)

    session.write(flowFile, OutputWrite(json.loads(r.text)))
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: just add some prints to console in your code to see where you loosing the data. the only point that i can see - you are reading the file as a text with `PyInputStreamCallback` but there could be a binary content..

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are actually sending the FlowFile contents.  Instead, you are sending an attribute named `file_content` as the file contents, which probably isn't what you intended

You will need to do a `session.read` to get the file stream. The below code doesn't work as is, but shows how you can get access to the stream.

```
class PyInputStreamCallback(InputStreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream):
    m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': (file_name, inputStream, 'application/pdf')})

session.read(flowFile, PyInputStreamCallback())
```

Ref: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75545/executescript-cookbook-part-2.html

Comment: Hello @Peter, I think I did that here --> "ExecuteScript Python - to convert the flowfile content to attribute". It's in [file_content]. I'll edit my question and include the code (not just the screenshot).

Comment: @Raii - Sorry, the image was a little small, so I made the assumption that it was the same processor your using to Post the data.  Anyways, I would suggest not doing it that way. Just combine them together into a single script, see how that goes.

Comment: Hello @Peter, I did my best and merged the code. I posted it as an update above. Can you help check if you have time? Thanks!